# Animation on View in ListView

Tags: android, animation

I have a ListView with a list of items. Every item has a little ImageButton with a star to mark it as a favorite. When the star ImageButton is clicked, I want it to do a little rotation. Works fine in Android 4.3, but on 2.3 not only the clicked star rotates, but also the star in the item above it.

I already tried to not use a ViewHolder for the star because I thought that might cause it, but that didn't help.

By the way, I do other stuff in the onClickListener, and that works fine and only for the clicked item.

What could be my problem?

This is part of my getView method in the list's adapter:

```
    CheckableImageButton favBtn = (CheckableImageButton) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.favbtn);

    favBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            v.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx,
                    R.anim.spinanim));

        }
    });
```

This is my whole getView method:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    checkLoadMore(position);

    final Item item = combinedResult.getItems().get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_fewo_v7, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.Iv = (RecyclingImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        holder.Tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.Tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.Tv3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        holder.Tv4 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        holder.Root = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.root);
        holder.Starbg = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.starbg);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    CheckableImageButton favBtn = (CheckableImageButton) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.favbtn);

    favBtn.setChecked(FavItems.contains(item.getGuid()));

    favBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (FavItems.contains(item.getGuid())) {
                FavItems.removeFav(item.getGuid());
            }

            else {
                FavItems.addFav(item);
            }

            v.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx,
                    R.anim.spinanim));

        }
    });

    holder.Tv1.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.Tv2.setText(item.getLocation().getDescription());
    holder.Tv3.setText(item.getPrice().getPriceText() + " "
            + item.getPrice().getPaymentIntervalShort());
    holder.Tv4.setText("bis " + item.getPersonsMax() + " Personen");

    displayImage(Tools.convertImageUrl(item.getThumbnailUrl()), holder.Iv,
            holder.Root);


    return convertView;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to use Tag. Use setTag() and getTag() methods to add tags to your image button, it would help you to identify which button is clicked.

Comment: post your getView() method implementation

Comment: Try using an AnimationListner,It might help

Comment: I have posted the whole method.

Comment: @Abhilash I don't see how that would help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to what [Gopal Rao](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19559950/2910492) says, you should use the convertView and the ViewHolder pattern. Also, you can move the FavBtn into the ViewHolder. You do need to clear the animation when the view is reused though, which is done in the else clause. The following should work:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;

    checkLoadMore(position);

    final Item item = combinedResult.getItems().get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_fewo_v7, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.Iv = (RecyclingImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        holder.Tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.Tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.Tv3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        holder.Tv4 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        holder.Root = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.root);
        holder.Starbg = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.starbg);
        holder.FavBtn = (CheckableImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.favbtn);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.FavBtn.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, R.anim.spinanim));
    }

    holder.FavBtn.setChecked(FavItems.contains(item.getGuid()));
    holder.FavBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (FavItems.contains(item.getGuid())) {
                FavItems.removeFav(item.getGuid());
            } else {
                FavItems.addFav(item);
            }

            holder.FavBtn.getAnimation().startNow();
        }
    });

    holder.Tv1.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.Tv2.setText(item.getLocation().getDescription());
    holder.Tv3.setText(item.getPrice().getPriceText() + " " + item.getPrice().getPaymentIntervalShort());
    holder.Tv4.setText("bis " + item.getPersonsMax() + " Personen");

    displayImage(Tools.convertImageUrl(item.getThumbnailUrl()), holder.Iv, holder.Root);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the effect of this is that the animation is not shown at all. I guess the animation is cleared to fast.

Comment: I updated the answer. Instead of clearing the animation, I set it in the else clause. Later when clicked, the animation is started. Please try if that works.

Comment: I found out why the animation clears so fast: when my favorite items change, the adapter is refreshed with notifyDataSetChanged(). I'll have so somehow delay that. 
But apart from that, your answer works, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        checkLoadMore(position);

        final Item item = combinedResult.getItems().get(position);

        convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_fewo_v7, null);

        RecyclingImageView Iv = (RecyclingImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        TextView Tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView Tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView Tv3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        TextView Tv4 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        RelativeLayout Root = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.root);
        RelativeLayout Starbg = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.starbg);



        CheckableImageButton favBtn = (CheckableImageButton) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.favbtn);

        favBtn.setChecked(FavItems.contains(item.getGuid()));

        favBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (FavItems.contains(item.getGuid())) {
                    FavItems.removeFav(item.getGuid());
                }

                else {
                    FavItems.addFav(item);
                }

                v.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx,
                        R.anim.spinanim));

            }
        });

        Tv1.setText(item.getTitle());
        Tv2.setText(item.getLocation().getDescription());
        Tv3.setText(item.getPrice().getPriceText() + " "
                + item.getPrice().getPaymentIntervalShort());
        Tv4.setText("bis " + item.getPersonsMax() + " Personen");

        displayImage(Tools.convertImageUrl(item.getThumbnailUrl()), Iv,
                Root);


        return convertView;
    }
```

stop null checking with convertview, because when convertview is not null, you are returning the same instance of view. so views which have same instance will have same animation

Comment: I tried it, it had no effect. Also, this would mean that I am not using the Viewholder at all, and the list gets real stuttery.